# css3 Transform: rotate moves the view

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I am currently trying to move the view in a pseudo 3D environment.
So I started with some divs and even got a first - lets call it room.

But now when I rotate, the view not only rotates, but also moves.
that makes it pretty hard to calculate at which position in the 3D real you are.

Any idea how to solve this.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/torsten/HHQCg/

and here is how I add the transformation to the div:

```
document.getElementById('world').style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateY(45deg)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's the **order** of the transforms.

Try rotating first:

```
function updateMap() {
    //alert(mapPos.rotate);
    document.getElementById('world').style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(" + mapPos.rotate + "deg) translate3d(" + mapPos.x +"px, " + mapPos.y + "px, " + mapPos.z + "px) ";
}
```

Comment: should not matter, as both is calculated and applied at the same time. But anyways I tested it. No

Comment: That's odd.  When I tested it...in Chrome, after I changed the order, it acted differently.

Comment: Yes, it matters, and a lot. If you are not aware of this, you will have a lot of problems. I would recommend you to do a quick search about "matrices product is not commutative", the issue is too long to explain it here. @SteveWellens is correctly answering you.

Comment: For sure that matters for other questions. I am sure that it matters a lot if take a turn of 90° and walk five feet or if you walk five feet and take a turn afterwards. But in my case both do not do the rotation in a spot, but seems always to rotate and move away. Plus you cannot do  a rotation and then move, as it is the same style command.